# POST request called twice given callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have some code in TypeScript to process Spotify's login flow, it looks like this:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import '@patternfly/react-core/dist/styles/base.css';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import env from "ts-react-dotenv";
interface Props {
    token: string;
}


const Callback: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
    const { token } = props;
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(token);
    const code = searchParams.get('code');
    var accessToken = '';
    // Create the POST request to get the access token
    const data = {
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
    };
    const body = new URLSearchParams();
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        if (value){
            body.append(key, value);
        }
    }
    const request = new Request('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(env.CLIENT_ID + ':' + env.CLIENT_SECRET),
        },
        body: body,
    });
    // Send the POST request
    fetch(request)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log("Access token: " + data.access_token);
            if (accessToken){
                accessToken = data.access_token;
            }
        });
    // Navigate to Home with the code
    // https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10803
    // Redirect to Home
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    setTimeout(() => navigate('/home', { state: { accessToken } }), 50);
    return <div>Loading... if the app doesn't work please reload</div>;

};
  
export default Callback;
```

I see that in the console there are 2 calls, the first one produces the correct result while there is somehow a second call that seems like its being made. I suspect that my post request somehow triggered another call within the callback field but I am not sure how that happened.

How can I fix this, set the correct access_token and go to the next page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the fetch call inside a useEffect hook, with dependency array as empty, Please refer [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

When we run the code on local server there component will be render at least 2 time, since CRA will create the code with strict mode.

```
import * as React from "react";
import "@patternfly/react-core/dist/styles/base.css";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import env from "ts-react-dotenv";
interface Props {
  token: string;
}

const Callback: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  const { token } = props;
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(token);
  const code = searchParams.get("code");
  var accessToken = "";
  // Create the POST request to get the access token
  const data = {
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/callback",
  };
  const body = new URLSearchParams();
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    if (value) {
      body.append(key, value);
    }
  }
  const request = new Request("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(env.CLIENT_ID + ":" + env.CLIENT_SECRET),
    },
    body: body,
  });
  // Send the POST request
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(request)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Access token: " + data.access_token);
        if (accessToken) {
          accessToken = data.access_token;
        }
      });
  }, []);
  // Navigate to Home with the code
  // https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10803
  // Redirect to Home
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  setTimeout(() => navigate("/home", { state: { accessToken } }), 50);
  return <div>Loading... if the app doesn't work please reload</div>;
};

export default Callback;
```

Comment: The redirection should must probably be within the callback of the fetch response.

Comment: Fixing the imports, a new problem stating that "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Cannot construct a Request with a Request object that has already been used" on line 36.